# How to implement the C flexible array member pattern in Rust?

Tags: rust, struct, flexible-array-member

I would like to implement this C code which uses a [*flexible array member*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) (sometimes called [the struct hack](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/struct-hack/)) in Rust:

```c
struct test {
  int key;
  int dataSize;
  int data[];
};
```

```c
struct test* t = malloc(sizeof(struct test) + sizeOfData)
```

The empty array at the end of structure allows you to allocate your meta fields and data all at once. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to do such thing in Rust.

Comment: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/emulating-c-flexible-array-members-in-rust/6262

Comment: I think you could achieve this on nightly with the allocator API and a decent amount of `unsafe`. But I'm not familiar enough with how it works in C. What if the alignment of the `data` array is bigger than the size of the header -- are padding bytes counted in the `sizeof`, or do we just rely on `malloc` allocating more than necessary to satisfy the maximum possible alignment?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Probably my fault because you can't avoid padding bytes like I said, both sizeof and offsetof must produce the same size for FAM.

Answer (score 2):

The Rust equivalent of this struct would use a slice:

```rust
struct test {
  key: i32,
  dataSize: i32,
  data: [i32],
}
```

however, these types are not really convenient to use at the moment as there is no safe way to construct them.

A more practical way to do this is to use a generic:

```rust
struct test<T: ?Sized> {
  key: i32,
  dataSize: i32,
  data: T,
}
```

and then to make sure that you only use `test` when `T` is an array or a slice (which you could only create through coercion).

See also:

- [Dynamically Sized Types (DSTs) on the nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/exotic-sizes.html#dynamically-sized-types-dsts)

Comment: no it's wrong, slice contains their len, FAM doesn't. There is no equivalent of FAM in Rust ATM.

Comment: @Stargateur `[T]` does not contain the length. You are talking about `&[T]` which is a fat pointer to a slice: that contains the length. But not the unsized `[T]` itself.

Comment: @JL2210 A fat pointer is a pointer + some extra data, for example `&[T]` is a fat pointer, as it contains the address to the first element + the size, and `&dyn Trait` is a fat pointer as it contains a pointer to the data + a pointer to the vtable.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt but this would not make sense in Rust, `[T]` need to know its size somehow, if you need unsafe this would not be Rust for me. Say [T] is the equivalent of FAM is wrong for me, at least for now.

Comment: Hoi! Could [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1861-extern-types.md#detailed-design) be the correct solution to all of this? At least pointers to structs with an extern type as last field are not fat pointers.