# How to pass pointer through [u8;1] member in struct when use ffi between Rust and C

Tags: c, rust, ffi

There is a struct in c

```
struct Foo{
    unsigned int    body_len;
    unsigned char   body[1];    
}
```

the question is how to define the Rust part of the struct Foo and how to create a Foo instance to be passed to the extern C function that accepts a Foo * as argument,  so body data can be accessed in C part. the body member will be converted to (unsigned char *) in c function.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64121094/5397009

Comment: Your question in title is not consistent with question in the body. In the title you're asking about passing a pointer though [u8;1] which seems to be strange. In the body you're asking about constructing rust representation of a C struct. So what are you actually asking about?

Comment: @Dmitry a common idiom in C consist in declaring a `struct` whose last member is an array of 1 element, or even an array with no size (`unsigned char body[];`), then to `malloc (sizeof (Foo) + body_len * sizeof (char))` so that the data can be put in the same allocation as `Foo`. Then `foo.body` can be used as if it was a pointer to the data. The question is obviously about reproducing this idiom in Rust.

Comment: If I understood correctly, it is simple `Unsized` struct in rust. Something like `struct { body_len: usize, body: [u8] }`. Of course, you must use `std::ffi::c_uint`, instead of `usize`, if you need native C's `int`. And don't forget `#[repr(C)]`

Comment: Sorry for my poor English and  late reply.  I've implemented it successfully with the help of a seasoned C programmer, It takes long before I realized I can't impl this without using unsafe. @Jmb explained my goal in deatil.Thanks to you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *theoretically* best Rust analogue of this struct declaration is:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
struct Foo {
    body_len: std::ffi::c_uint,
    body: [std::ffi::c_uchar],
}
```

This is a [custom dynamically sized type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/exotic-sizes.html#dynamically-sized-types-dsts); the compiler knows that its size varies. However, there is a catch: working with such types involves “fat pointers” or “wide pointers” which store the length *in the pointer, not in the struct*. So you'll find it difficult to pass around `&Foo`s or even `*const Foo`s because the compiler will demand that you construct the pointer with a redundant length (and it's difficult to actually do that with the currently stable operations).

Therefore, in order to deal with the *internally* specified length (that is, in a field in the same struct), you'll need to give up and take essentially the same approach as in the C code, of providing a dummy field marking the start of the data which is bigger than the `Foo`. However, unlike standard C, Rust doesn't demand that arrays have size of at least 1, so we can arrange things more sensibly.

```rust
#[repr(C)]
struct Foo {
    body_len: std::ffi::c_uint,
    body: [std::ffi::c_uchar; 0],
}
```

You can then use pointer operations to access the `body`. (You must not use references, because while the exact semantics are not yet decided, it *might* be UB to access “past the end” of a reference's referent.) Note that getting this right is quite tricky; you should ask for a code review of whatever code you actually write, and also test your code under [Miri](https://github.com/rust-lang/miri) (as far as possible, avoiding the actual FFI parts), to have sufficient confidence that it is sound and correct.

Here is a complete example of how this might be done, providing a safe `BoxFoo` type that can allocate `Foo`s and hand out pointers to them. I'm not myself an expert on this particular kind of pointer trickery, so please don't take it as the definitely best way to do this.

```rust
use std::{alloc, ptr};
use std::ffi::{c_uint, c_uchar};

#[repr(C)]
struct Foo {
    body_len: c_uint,
    body: [c_uchar; 0],
}

/// An owner for a heap allocated [`Foo`] that understands its length.
/// (We can't use `Box` because it assumes that `size_of::<Foo>()` is the entire size.)
struct BoxFoo {
    foo: *mut Foo,
}

impl BoxFoo {
    /// Computes the layout for allocating a `Foo` of a given size.
    fn layout(body_len: c_uint) -> alloc::Layout {
        let byte_len = usize::try_from(body_len).expect("body_len overflowed usize");
        let (layout, _) = alloc::Layout::new::<Foo>()
            .extend(alloc::Layout::array::<c_uchar>(byte_len).unwrap())
            .unwrap();
        layout
    }

    pub fn new(bytes_to_copy: &[c_uchar]) -> Self {
        let body_len: std::ffi::c_uint = bytes_to_copy.len().try_into().expect("body too long");
        let layout = Self::layout(body_len);

        // SAFETY:
        // * The preconditions of `alloc::alloc()` are met because we know `Foo` has nonzero size
        //   even if its data is nonzero.
        // * The pointer write operations write into memory we just allocated to be big enough.
        let foo = unsafe {
            // Allocate enough memory for the data.
            let ptr: *mut Foo = alloc::alloc(layout).cast::<Foo>();
            if ptr.is_null() {
                alloc::handle_alloc_error(layout);
            }

            // Initialize the fixed part of the struct
            ptr::write(ptr, Foo { body_len, body: [] });
            // Initialize the variable length part
            let body_array_ptr: *mut [c_uchar; 0] = ptr::addr_of_mut!((*ptr).body);
            std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(
                bytes_to_copy.as_ptr(),
                body_array_ptr.cast::<c_uchar>(),
                bytes_to_copy.len(),
            );
            ptr
        };

        Self { foo }
    }

    pub fn as_ptr(&self) -> *const Foo {
        self.foo
    }

    pub fn body(&self) -> &[c_uchar] {
        // SAFETY: `Foo` has the invariant that `body_len` shall be no longer than is
        // actually allocated after the `Foo` structure.
        unsafe {
            std::slice::from_raw_parts(
                ptr::addr_of!((*self.foo).body).cast::<c_uchar>(),
                usize::try_from((*self.foo).body_len).expect("body_len overflowed usize"),
            )
        }
    }
}

impl std::ops::Deref for BoxFoo {
    type Target = Foo;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        // SAFETY: It is an invariant of this type that the pointer points to a valid Foo.
        unsafe { &*self.foo }
    }
}

impl Drop for BoxFoo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let layout = Self::layout(unsafe { (*self.foo).body_len });
        // SAFETY: It is an invariant of this type that the pointer is a current allocation of
        // this layout.
        unsafe {
            alloc::dealloc(self.foo.cast::<u8>(), layout);
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn alloc_use_dealloc() {
    let data = b"hello world";
    let foo = BoxFoo::new(data);
    assert_eq!(foo.body(), data);
    drop(foo);
}
```

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible to do it in rust https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51005645/how-to-implement-the-c-flexible-array-member-pattern-in-rust

Comment: @Stargateur If you think the code in my post is incorrect (other than the first block which is hypothetical), please tell me where.

Comment: well like in C it's hard to predict such code, and exactly like in C, Rust could assume the array is zero size cause you declare it as such, that why in C FAM are declared without a size and not a size of zero, in future your code could blow or other compiler of rust could assume your code is UB. That hard to say. For now I guess it's correct. I think code that deal with FAM of C should use C code to manage it.

Comment: @Stargateur That's why my code avoids making a *reference* to the `Foo`. The semantics of references are not yet nailed down, but it's quite certain that *pointers*  do not constrain access to the size of the pointee. If they did, [`std::slice::from_raw_parts()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html) would be useless. (That's an important distinction to make, though, so I updated the answer to clarify.)